# Python/Pandas - how can I avoid ellipsis when using 'describe'

Tags: python, file-io, pandas

I am opening a file with many features in iPython notebook (~145k observations, ~ 2000 features).  When using df.describe, the output uses ellipsis in summarizing the features. How can I output the description of all the rows to a file?

```
[In]
url = "some large file"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.describe()

[Out]
       Col 1    Col 2    Col 3    Col 4   ...  Col 1998   Col 1999   Col 2000
mean   Blah     Blah     Blah     Blah    ...  Blah       Blah       Blah
std
min 
etc
```

I thought I could avoid the ellipsis by writing the output to a file:

```
[In]
url1 = "Some output file"
f = open(url1, 'w')
f.write(str(df.describe()))
f.close()
```

But the file looks the same as the output.

Comment: did you try running this as a script outside of iPython notebook? notebook may be the culprit here.

Comment: @Incognos No....I'd like to address this within notebook if possible, as I prefer doing initial work within this framework.

Comment: @GPB that's fine, but Incognos' suggestion was to *try* it outside of iPython notebook in order to determine if notebook is the cause of the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @GPB I know that notebook and most python interactive interpreters do the ellipsis thing as a way to manage display. give it a shot to eliminate the possibility

Comment: won't `df.describe().to_csv(file_path)` just work?

Comment: @dimo414 - thanks for your exhortation.    I think the answer below has solved  my question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`pd.options.display.max_columns = 2000`

If you don't want to make the change permanently for the notebook, (e.g., to avoid excessive output in other cells), you can also use `pd.option_context`:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', 2000):
     print(df.describe())
```

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't have more upvotes. Supremely useful tip. Thanks Randy!!!